# Correct Way to Retrieve Header Records With Filtered Detail Records

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I wrote this in LinqPad. It works. The whole point was to retrieve header records, and only include *some* detail records. I'm looking for possible improvements to this, specifically around the anonymous type part. The only way I was able to get this to work as to use an anonymous type, then create the `ToEntitySet()` extension method to convert the detail rows. I just feel like I'm making this harder than it is. But maybe not? Any comments are welcome.

```
void Main()
{
    var query =
        from header in AccountHeader
        join detail in AccountDetail 
            on header.AccountHeaderId equals detail.AccountHeaderId
            into groupedDetails
        where groupedDetails.Any(x => x.Status == "status2")
        select new
        {
            Account = header,
            AccountDetail = groupedDetails.Where(x => x.Status == "status2")
        };

    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        var account = item.Account;
        account.AccountDetail = item.AccountDetail.ToEntitySet();
        account.Dump();
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static EntitySet<T> ToEntitySet<T> (this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : class
    {
        var entitySet = new EntitySet<T> ();
        entitySet.AddRange (source);
        return entitySet;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to _unfoo_ your code and post the real one. Currently this is off-topic.

Comment: Why do I need to unfoo my code? How does that make a difference?

Comment: Because Code Review is about improving working and real code and not hypothetical one. Please take a look at the [help].

Comment: Well, I'm stuck then, because my company doesn't want me to post our types. I'm really struggling to understand how it really matters. This *is* real code, with just a couple of types renamed. Does that really alter the overall understanding of what I've posted?

Comment: Maybe try to find different names that still make sense and don't look like pseudocode... It's really hard to follow _foos_. We don't know your code and seeting only _garbage_ isn't helping to understand it.

Comment: Ok, I just changed it.

Comment: Yeah that is much clearer now.

Comment: That was sarcasm.